My widgets in iOS 18 don't work anymore, getTimeline method gets called in loop
I’m encountering an issue with my widgets on iOS 18 beta 8, where the getTimeline method is being called repeatedly and ignoring the timeline update intervals.
This problem doesn’t occur on iOS 17, where the same code works perfectly.
I can't get to find in the Apple documentation the things that could have led to this problem, do someone has some assistance?
The only thing I could think about it, is that I'm doing some network calls in the widget, and that maybe the widget is calling the getTimeline method before finishing.
Do someone else have any advice?
here some code:
func getTimeline(for configuration: MyIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<ImageWidgetEntry>) -> Void) {
    let id = UUID()
    let gallery = configuration.gallery
    guard let sharedUserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: Constants.appGroup) else {
        debugPrint("Failed to access UserDefaults")
        return
    }
    
    checkAndUpdatePremiumStatusIfNeeded { isPro in
        var hasProFeatures = false
        if let galleryIdentifier = gallery?.identifier {
            let components = galleryIdentifier.components(separatedBy: "|")
            let widgetId = String(components[1])
            let uuid = String(components[3])
            
            let isPinned = sharedUserDefaults.bool(forKey: "isPinned_\(widgetId)_\(uuid)")
            let isTimerUpdate = UserDefaultsManager.shared.getWidgetTimerUpdateFlag(for: widgetId, uuid: uuid)
            
            if isPinned || isTimerUpdate {
                // Normal timeline creation logic...
                let entry = ImageWidgetEntry(date: Date(), image: UIImage(), id: id, isWidgetAdded: true, configuration: configuration, isPinned: isPinned)
                let updateInterval = isPro ? 240 : 60
                let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(updateInterval * 60))))
                completion(timeline)
            }
        }
    }
}

What I tried:
•   Verified that checkAndUpdatePremiumStatusIfNeeded completes correctly before calling the completion handler.
•   Verified that no part of the widget logic is accidentally forcing an update and that i don't have any WidgetKit force reload at all
I tried also to reboot Xcode and phone too, because the Xcode 16.0 beta 6 is not working good: I get often this error:
SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=32 "Show Notification Center Widget timed out."


If you do a sample app with a timeline does it also happen? (Easy way to rule out bugs in your code)

I have noticed a change between iOS 17 and iOS 18 in the way the getTimeline function is called. In my particular case, on iOS 17 the getTimeline was called at specific times respecting the .never update strategy. On iOS 18, the getTimeline is called twice for every button interaction, UI entry update, etc. In your case, iOS 18 is probably not respecting your timing, which may affect your logic. Can't find the reason on the documentation but you definitely have to make your widgets state management code more robust for iOS 18. Also, I would recommend migrating to AppIntentConfiguration

Thank you very much for you comment @PauloSilva!! at least I'm not mad :D I'm seeing the exact same thing you're describing and I can't find anything about this in the documentation.
I'll look into the AppIntentConfiguration and see if it could help me. Thanks!
